# Wifi Socket address not valid,Android

Tags: java, android, sockets

Whenever I create a `ServerSocket` and watch the socket address by calling `getLocalSocketAddress()`, I see:

> 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:xxxxx( xxxx is random port no)

My code for server is:

```
try{
    Boolean end = false;
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(0);
    System.out.println("Program running, Server address:" + ss.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());
    while(!end){
        //Server is waiting for client here, if needed

        Socket s = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Socket Connected !");  
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true); //Autoflush
        String st = input.readLine();
        System.out.println("Tcp Example From client: "+st);
        output.println("Good bye and thanks for all the fish :)");
        s.close();

    }
    ss.close();  
 } catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Notes: 1. You should use `Log` instead of `System.out.println()` 2. ss is out of scope, e.g. the compiler should complain that it is an unknown variable.

Comment: sorry for not pasting the whole code. There is not compiler error as such, Its just because the whole code was not coming inside code section in my question thats why I didnt copy whole code

Answer (score 0):

**Dont** assign **"0" in ServerSocket**

**Ports are from 0-65535 , but its 1 - 65534 to be used.. MoreOver try to use ports above 1024, as its used by other well known services, like Telnet, FTP, HTTP, etc...**

See my code...it might help you execute your code.....

**The Server side code example:**

```
    public class ServerTest {

        ServerSocket s;

        public void go() {

            try {
                s = new ServerSocket(4445);

                while (true) {

                    Socket incoming = s.accept();
                    Thread t = new Thread(new MyCon(incoming));
                    t.start();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        class MyCon implements Runnable {

            Socket incoming;

            public MyCon(Socket incoming) {

                this.incoming = incoming;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream(),
                            true);
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                            incoming.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    String inp = null;

                    boolean isDone = true;

                    System.out.println("TYPE : BYE");
                    System.out.println();
                    while (isDone && ((inp = br.readLine()) != null)) {

                        System.out.println(inp);
                        if (inp.trim().equals("BYE")) {
                            System.out
                                    .println("THANKS FOR CONNECTING...Bye for now");
                            isDone = false;
                            s.close();
                        }

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    try {
                        s.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            new ServerTest().go();

        }

}
```

Comment: I think now problem is not with server code, I am trying to exchange packet between android device and my computer. So in Client code what Socket address should be used ?

Comment: @Kumar Vivek Mitra: according to the documentation: `public ServerSocket (int port) - Constructs a new ServerSocket instance bound to the given port. The backlog is set to 50. If port == 0, a port will be assigned by the OS.`

Comment: @bicska88 i got a doubt..how will the client know which port is server running on...if its assigned by the OS.

Comment: @Kumar Vivek Mitra: It is correct what you are saying, what I wanted to point out is that this is definitely **NOT** the cause of the problem.

Comment: @David Kroukamp, why use public IP, does he has a static Public IP address, i bet if its his home pc..it will be using NAT, if thats the case he need to use some mechanism to you his dynamic ip as static... Now, If he want to run that application for trying out the code..he can use ANY IP, PUBLIC OR PRIVATE, IT WILL NOT MATTER UNTIL HE IS TAKING THE APP ON INTERNET...

Comment: @Kumar Vivek Mitra, Hmm yes this is true, never though about that! Thank you

Comment: Private ips Class A - 10.X.X.X   Class B - 172.16.X.X-172.31.X.X and Class C - 192.168.X.X , other are all Public Ips.....`But if he just want to try his code, without taking it on the internet, he can use any either private or public, it wont matter`

Comment: Let him try using a simple socket connection first.. `According to my code the Server will run at 4445 port on the host.. and He can replace the LocalHost with any ip he wants..`